# Group By in SOQL query using calendar week from Sunday to Saturday

Tags: soql, group-by

I have a query that I'm working on where I need to group by in a calendar week that starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday.

I was trying this: `GROUP BY WEEK_IN_YEAR(Start_Time__c)`

This was close, but it goes from Jan. 1 - 7, 8 - 14, etc. It doesn't start from the start of the week beginning on a Sunday.

Is there a way to the grouping so it starts on Sunday ends on Saturday for a calendar week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by a formula that offsets the date (i.e. Start_Time__c - 2) such that WEEK_IN_YEAR(Formula_Field__c) will return the same value for all (and only) days in the same calendar week.

To elaborate, if the year started on a Sunday, GROUP BY WEEK_IN_YEAR would work perfectly for that entire year, so if the first Sunday is actually the third day of the year (and second Sunday, the 10th etc), simply deduct 2 days to get to the same effect as if it were perfectly aligned.

You can put an IF condition, where you change the offset depending on the year. The formula would be deducting the number day of the year of the first Sunday minus 1. (So in 2021, Jan **3** was on Sunday, so you deduct 3-1).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by offsetting the date? WEEK_IN_YEAR returns a number based on the week in the calendar year, so how would offset the date field so it would consistently run from Sunday to Saturday. My apologies if I'm misunderstanding. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Jan 1, 2021 was on Friday. Let's say you want Jan 3-9, 2021 to be group 1, and Jan 10-16, group 2 etc. in the formula field, deduct 2 days from Start_Time__c. You can have an IF statement so that the offset changes depends on the year (deduct the number of the first day of the month that was on Sunday minus one). Maybe Ill edit my main post for clarity.

Comment: @Dman100 See updated post. Let me know if its more clear.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely clear! Thank you very much! I appreciate the clarification. I'll give it a try and post back if I run into any other issues. Thanks again!